# ParseError: "Erreur lors de la validation de la contrainte

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

> ParseError: "Erreur lors de la validation de la contrainte
>
> Le champ `nameLab` n'existe pas

```xml
 <field name="order_line" mode="tree,kanban">
     <tree string="labs Order Lines" editable="bottom" >
             <field name="nameLab" />
     </tree>                                
</field>
```

```py
class test1 (models.Model):
    _name = "test1"
    order_line = fields.One2many('test2', 'order_id', string='Order Lines', copy=True)
    nameLab = fields.Many2one('a_model',related='order_line.namelab',string='name Lab', store=True)
    
    
    
class test2(models.Model):
    _name = 'test2'
    namelab=fields.Many2one(comodel_name='a_model',
        required=True, ondelete='cascade',)
```

***EDITS:***

the whole view

```xml
<record id="view_invoice_lab_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">lab.invoice.form</field>
            <field name="model">lab.invoice</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Labs Invoices" class="o_sale_order">
                <header>
                   
                </header>
                <sheet>
                  

                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <h1>
                            <field name="name" readonly="1"/>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="T1" />
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="T2" />
                            <field name="T3"/>
                            <field name="T4"/>
                           <!-- <field name="sequence"/>
                             <field name="name"/>  -->
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Order Lines">
                            <field name="order_line" mode="tree,kanban">
                                <tree string="labs Order Lines" editable="bottom" >
                                  
                                       
                                         <field name="nameLab" /> 
                                </tree>                                
                            </field>
                        </page>
                   
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
        
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

```py
    @api.onchange('nameLab')
    def onchange_nameLab(self):
        
        if self.nameLab:
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the whole view ? Not just this field.

Comment: I just added the whole view

Comment: Have you restart the service ?

Comment: When you add a new field you must restart the service and update the module

Comment: of course I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test2` does not have a field `nameLab`, but it has a field `namelab` (see the capital L).

An explanation :

```
<tree string="labs Order Lines" editable="bottom" >
     <field name="nameLab" />
</tree>
```

Here, you're rendering `test2` (the One2many `order_line` is a One2many of `test2`) and not `test1`.

Comment: I have another problem now is that my onchange doesn't work anymore see the edits plw

Comment: Is this method on `test1` ? I don't think you should put `@api.multi` on `onchange` methods. Also, do you set a field when `nameLab` changes ? Because that is what we normally do inside `onchange` methods. I don't know because your code seem to be incomplete.

Comment: yes this method is on test1. I agree about @api.multi . I changed my code, I ll be thankful if you can see the edits

Comment: what I need is once I select a nameLab the other fields have their values

Comment: Not sure. Although this looks like a brand new question actually. You should start a new thread (new question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150971/discussion-between-sos-mona-and-majikat).